# Swift: child class return parent class properties

Tags: swift, swift2

I have the following situation, the real code is way more, but this provide a nice sum of the situation. (if you are wondering the use of this is to have a dynamically loaded UICollectionView):

```
protocol P {
    static var name: String {get}
}

extension P {
    static var name: String {
       return String(Self)
    }
}

protocol P2 {
    getType() -> P.Type
    getName() -> String
}

class A: P {
}

class B: A {
}

class C1: P2 {
    func getType() -> P.Type {
       return A.self
    }

    func getName() -> String {
       return A.name
    }
}

class C2: P2 {
    func getType() -> P.Type {
       return B.self
    }

    func getName() -> String {
       return B.name
    }
}
```

now what's happening is the following:

```
 C1.getType().name //"A" as expected
 C1.getName()      //"A" as expected
 C2.getType().name //"A" why?
 C2.getName()      //"B" as expected
```

I don't have any clue why `C2.getType.name` returns "A". I checked in the debugger and the function is executed correctly, The type returned by C2 is B.

I'm using XCode 7.3 with Swift 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because protocol extensions are not polymorphic. The implementation of `name` is in a protocol extension, and reads:

```
static var name: String {
   return String(Self)
}
```

`Self` is the adopter. Who is it that adopts P? It's A:

```
class A: P {
}
```

And that's as far as things go; `Self` in this context is not interpreted polymorphically. If you wanted polymorphism, you'd need to implement `name` in the classes themselves — just as you did with `getName`.

Comment: Ok got it, I'll just implement the needed methods in the child class, thanks!